# Fortify not finding .NET assemblies

Tags: .net, fortify

I am trying to setup a Fortify scan, but it keeps giving me errors like this:

> Cannot locate class 'System.Object' in the given search path and the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework libraries

I have added the .NET assembly locations to the command line, but it still fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortify tries to locate the .NET assemblies and cache them.  It looks for Visual Studio in the Windows registry to find what .NET version it should use.

You need to use `-vsversion` to specify the version of Visual Studio that was used in creating the .NET code:

- VS2005 = 8.0
- VS2008 = 9.0
- VS2010 = 10.0
- VS2012 = 11.0
- VS2013 = 12.0
- VS2015 = 14.0

If that does not do it, use:

```
-Dvs.<VS Ver w/o the .>.dotnet.clr.version=<CLR version>
```

For example, VS2012:

```
sourceanalyzer -b MyProj -vsversion 11.0 <your translation args>
```

or:

```
sourceanalyzer -b MyProj -vsversion 11.0 -Dvs.110.dotnet.clr.version=v4.0.30319
```

Here are all the VS "fallback" args:

```
-Dvs.110.dotnet.clr.version=v4.0.30319
-Dvs.100.dotnet.clr.version=v4.0.30319
-Dvs.90.dotnet.clr.version=v2.0.50727
-Dvs.80.dotnet.clr.version=v2.0.50727
-Dvs.71.dotnet.clr.version=v2.0.50727
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Now just have to fix parser errors :(

Comment: If you have specifics you can share, ask another question and we can work out the issues.

Comment: Does this advice still work with Fortify 4.21? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4.5 and tried using **-vsversion 12.0 -Dvs.112.dotnet.clr.version=v4.5.50938** along with exact lines copy/pasted from your answer. Every time I get an error **the property vs.112.dotnet...** is not a valid property.

Comment: Yes sorry I typed that by hand instead of copying it and failed :) Here is the warning I get: [warning]: The property vs.120.dotnet.clr.version is not a valid property.

[edit] The entire line is: ***sourceanalyzer -vsversion 12.0 -b buildid -64 -Xmx3G -libdirs supportFiles;bin -Dvs.120.dotnet.clr.version=4.5.50938 -dotnet-sources . .***

Comment: Wouldn't the CLR version for VS 2013 (v 12.0) still be v4.0.30319 ? that may have been your issue